# wait for for loop to finish before executing next function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to wait for my for loop to be completed before i can start using the 'experimentArray'. How do i wait until this is complete before i move onto using the experimentArray? i've tried promises, async await, etc

```
 let experimentArray = []
     for (i = 0; i < this.state.gameRoomMembers.length; i++) {
            firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(this.state.gameRoomMembers[i]).collection('groupChats').get().then(snapshot => {
                 if (!snapshot.empty) {
                      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                          experimentArray.push(doc.data().key)
                       })
                 }
             })
}
console.log(experimentArray.length) // outputs 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is expected, as the `get()` calls to Firestore are asynchronous.

You can't really *wait* for them. But with `await` (or even `Promise.all()`) you can get pretty close:

```
let promises = [];
for (i = 0; i < this.state.gameRoomMembers.length; i++) {
  promises.push(firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(this.state.gameRoomMembers[i]).collection('groupChats').get());
}
let experimentArray = []
Promise.all(promises).then(snapshots => {
  snapshot.forEach(snapshot => {
     if (!snapshot.empty) {
       snapshot.forEach(doc => {
         experimentArray.push(doc.data().key)
       })
     }
  })
});
console.log(experimentArray.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

I prefer that to prevent allocating memory.